# Bitly returns with MISSING_ARG_LOGIN when I try to shorten my link

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to shorten my link with the following using post man:

```
http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?callback=?login=xxxxxx&apiKey=xxxxxx4a58968824c71e281208&longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fbetaworks.com%2F&format=json
```

When I run the above I get the following:

```
{
"status_code": 500,
"status_txt": "MISSING_ARG_LOGIN",
"data": []
}
```

But based on what I see here:

[Using Only Javascript To Shrink URLs Using The Bit.ly API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760538/using-only-javascript-to-shrink-urls-using-the-bit-ly-api)

I do not think anything is missing. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the last question mark with ampersand:

```
http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?callback=&login=xxxxxx&apiKey=...
```

I had the same problem with c# (httpclient).
Response code was 200 but response content contains **missing_arg_login**

In my case, bitly api needs a trailing slash for baseadress

Fails

```
BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4")
```

Works

```
BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/")
```

Answer (score 1):

With API V4 the schema has changed. You must send your generic token as a bearer in the header. EG `Authorization: Bearer token`

This endpoint has also changed to a post. Essentially it will look like this

`https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4`
`Headers` `Authorization: Bearer xyz`
`Body`: `{long_url = "xyz"}`

Their documentation is a little lacking. No where could I find how you were supposed to send the generic token.

Comment: Feel free to check out this link on how to use Bitly V4, It explains where and how to send the generic token.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431374/bitly-api-how-to-generate-oauth2-token-to-integrate-with-bitly-api-v4-and-make/59431375#59431375

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and by simply opening a tab in POSTMAN and creating a new request with the Header information fixed it.

If anyone ever has any trouble generating an OAuth token in version 4 of Bitly please refer to this [step-by-step guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431374/bitly-api-how-to-generate-oauth2-token-to-integrate-with-bitly-api-v4-and-make/59431375#59431375) I posted.