# Integrate to Bit.ly API Version 4 - How to Generate OAuth2 Token to integrate with Bit.ly API V4 and create a shortened url?

Tags: rest, api, postman, bit.ly

I was having the hardest time trying to generate the ***OAuth2 token*** to integrate with the **Bitly API v4**. Their documentation was hard to comprehend and I couldn't find much online or on StackOverflow on how to accomplish it. I was able to get it to work and wanted to share the solution for anyone else who will be scratching their heads in the future.

Below is a step-by-step guide for Generating ***Generic Access Token***, Retrieving the ***Group Guid***, ***Generating the OAuth2 token***, and calling the Bitly ***shorten*** API request.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Bitly API**- *Steps to get **oAuth2 Access token** and using the **shorten** request to retrieve a Tiny Url using **Postman**:*

After spending the better half of a day trying to figure this out I figured I would post this so it could help someone trying to integrate with ***Bitly API V4***.

**Note:** ***Bitly API V3 will be deactivated on March 1st, 2020 so be sure to migrate to V4 as soon as possible. All the guids and other private fields in the responses have been altered for privacy.***

**Click this link to refer to the [Bitly API Documentation](https://dev.bitly.com/v4_documentation.html)**

1.) **Generate Access Token:**

Log into bitly.com with your credentials and click on the Hamburger menu in the top right. Click on your Username and then click on the ***Generic Access Token***. This ***Generic Access token*** is needed to retrieve your ***Group Guid***. You will need this Group Guid to make the shorten URL Request along with your access token.

2.) **Retrieve Group Guid:**

Make a **GET** Request to https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/groups to get your group_guid. ***You will use your Generic Access Token in the Authorization Field***.

*Below is a picture how the Headers should look:*

[image: Group Guid Headers]

You should get a JSON Response back that looks similar to the JSON below:

**JSON Response of the Retrieve Group Guid GET Response:**

```
{
    "groups": [
        {
            "created": "2019-12-18T13:45:21+0000",
            "modified": "2019-12-18T13:45:21+0000",
            "bsds": [],
            "guid": "XZXUYSJAJ43", 
            "organization_guid": "JsjFtE841883",
            "name": "username",
            "is_active": true,
            "role": "org-admin",
            "references": {
                "organization": "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/organizations/JsjFtE841883"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Your *guid* value is your ***group_guid*** used in your shorten, and other requests.

3.) **Retrieve your client_id and client_secret**

Register your application by logging into bitly.com with your user credentials and your application will be assigned a client_id and a client_secret. You can accomplish this by clicking on the Hamburger menu on the right side of the page, **click on your username, Registered OAuth Apps, and at the bottom their should be a button** that says ***REGISTER NEW APP***.

4.) **Generate OAuth2 Access Token**

Refer to the [Bitly Documentation](https://dev.bitly.com/v4_documentation.html) and under the Authentication tab navigate to ***"Exchanging a Username and Password for an Access Token"***.

•   Open Postman

•   Create a new **POST** request to https://api-ssl.bitly.com/oauth/access_token.

•   Copy the Curl Command but replace username with Bitly Login Username and password with your Bitly Login Password.

•   Click on the Import tab and select Past Raw Text and paste over curl command

•   In the Authorization tab paste your ***client_id*** into the **Username** field and ***client_secret*** into the **Password** field. This will do the *base64encoding* for you.

•   Your Headers only need the **Host** and **Content-Type** key and Value. Your **Authorization** will be be a temporary header field and will be automatically generated for you.

•   Your Body needs:

**grant_type**: *password (the actual word password)*

**username**: *your username for bitly.com*

**password**: *your password for for bitly.com*

*Below is a picture of what your Body should look like:*

[image]

•   Click **Send** and you will receive your access token.

5.) **Shorten URL**

•   Open new tab in Postman and make a Post request to https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten

•   **Headers** should include:

•   **Host**: *api-ssl.bitly.com*

•   **Authorization**: *Bearer (your accesstoken from step 4)*

•   **Content-Type**: *application/json*

•   Your **Body** should include this JSON:

```
{
  "long_url": "http://twitter.com",
  "group_guid": "guid field from Group Guid Response in Step 2"
}
```

•   Click **Send** and  you should see get a JSON Response like this:

```
{
    "created_at": "2019-12-18T21:50:47+0000",
    "id": "yhoo/2PYRS",
    "link": "http://yhoo/2PYRS",
    "custom_bitlinks": [],
    "long_url": "http://yahoo.com/",
    "archived": false,
    "tags": [],
    "deeplinks": [],
    "references": {
        "group": "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/groups/yourgroupguid"
    }
}
```

**The *link* value in the JSON Response will be your new Tiny URL Link.**

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed solution. I have been looking everywhere for reliable documentation to migrate to Bitly API V4 since V3 is being deactivated. And here I finally found it.

Comment: @brasfan I’m glad it helped! Hope it helps others as well. Please upvote if it helped you in anyway.