# How to Use Bitly Api to create Link in Flutter App with dart

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I don't have much experience with Api as I searched but could not find  a good resource on this the UI and action code is done but does not worth mentioning

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is missing information and clarity. To improve your odds of receiving quality answers, please follow the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This link is a step by step guide on how to Get the *access token*, generate the *OAuth2 Token*, and generate a *shortened url* using **Bitly API v4**. This is an example using **Postman** to make the API calls, but it will definitely get you started in the right direction. As far as the integrating it with a Flutter App with dart you would have to provide some code and the community can help you. I hope this helps!

[Click this link and you will find the guide.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431374/bitly-api-how-to-generate-oauth2-token-to-integrate-with-bitly-api-v4-and-make/59431375#59431375)

[Bitly API - How to Generate OAuth2 Token to integrate with Bitly API V4 and make API requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431374/bitly-api-how-to-generate-oauth2-token-to-integrate-with-bitly-api-v4-and-make/59431375#59431375)

Answer (score -1):

Here you try below plugin which support bitly & other provider url shortner.

- [flutter_url_shortener](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_url_shortener)
- [flutter_shortener](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_shortener/)
- [bitly](https://pub.dev/packages/bitly)